# magento error after instal

Tags: magento2, database, installation

after install magento I have error:

```
An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

in **exception**:

```
main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` at W:\\domains\\localhost\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Statement\\Pdo\\Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.core_config_data' doesn't exist at W:\\domains\\localhost\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Statement\\Pdo\\Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

How can I rewrite the path to the database? Ty for answer

Comment: check database missing core_config_data table ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the prefix in the database or you can execute the setup upgrade command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`